# Update Site URL with Custom Webpack Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to customize the build process for my react project. I am using a custom script `npm run release` that is set up like this in the package.json file:

```json
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "release": "npx webpack --config webpack.config.js",
        ...
        ...
```

My webpack.config.js file is in the root directory of the project, and looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const entryPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/index.tsx');
const outputPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build');

const output = {
    path: outputPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
};

const rules = [
    {
        test: /.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            },
        },
    },
    {
        test: /.tsx?$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                transpileOnly: true,
            },
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
    },
    {
        test: /.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
            filename: '[name][ext]',
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.json$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
            filename: '[name][ext]',
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.ico$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
            filename: '[name][ext]',
        },
    },
];

const devServer = {
    contentBase: outputPath,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
};

const resolve = {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
};

const plugins = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public/index.html'),
        favicon: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public/favicon.ico'),
        robots: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public/robots.txt'),
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: 'public/*.png', to: '[name][ext]' },
            { from: 'public/manifest.json', to: '[name][ext]' },
        ],
    }),
];

module.exports = {
    entry: entryPath,
    output,
    module: {
        rules,
    },
    mode: 'development', // or 'production' or 'none'
    devServer,
    resolve,
    plugins,
};
```

When I run `npm run release`, I see the generated /build folder with all of the necessary bundled JS files, favicon, and index.html. However, the index.html file still has the URL env variable - `%PUBLIC_URL%` - whenever it is referenced, such as:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
...
...
```

Is there a problem with my webpack.config.js file that is causing the actual URL for my site to not populate the index.html file? When I do the traditional `npm run build`, I get the build/index.html file with the correct URL. Any help is greatly appreciated